# SEARCH GAL on the Exchange server

Tags: android, exchange-server, msdn, exchangewebservices

I need to get the Contacts of  GAL from exchange server..

I have a method  that searches the GAL on the Exchange server

for that there is

**`query string  :   The name to search the GAL for....`**

the code is given as follows....

```
public int searchGAL(
            String query, 
            StringBuffer result) throws Exception 
    {
        // Create the request

        String uri = mUri + "Search";


String  xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                + "<Search xmlns=\"Search:\">\n" + 
                "\t<Store>\n"
                + "\t\t<Name>GAL</Name>\n" 
                + "\t\t<Query>" + query + "</Query>\n" 
                + "\t\t<Options>\n"
                + "\t\t\t<Range>0-99</Range>\n"
                + "\t\t</Options>\n"
                + "\t</Store>\n"
                + "</Search>";

               // Send it to the server
        HttpResponse response = sendPostRequest(createHttpPost(uri,xml,true));  

        // Check the response code to see if the result was 200
        // Only then try to decode the content

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if(statusCode == 200)
        {
            // Decode the XML content
            result.append(decodeContent(response.getEntity())); 
        }

// parse and return the results
        return statusCode;
    }
```

How to get the the all contacts in the server,.. how to query that ??

when i give space.. the query will search the names starting with space.. but i need to return all contacts when i pass space as query string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631384(v=exchg.80).aspx